# Java: Calling a constructor of a class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, constructor

I have an ArrayList that holds objects of possibly different classes, and need to call the classes constructors.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

list.add(new Child1());
list.add(new Child2());

public void Spawn(){

Class clazz = list.get(0).getClass();

list.add(clazz.getConstructor().newInstance());
}
```

How can I achieve this? The last line in the code returns an error because the `clazz.getConstructor().newInstance()` returns an object, not an instance of child1. The different list items will all have a common parent, and in fact the items on the list can even all be the same, but i just can't hard-code the class name into the program.

Edit:
I may have stripped down the example too far.

I basically have a class that manipulates ArrayLists and needs to add new instances of the objects already inside, but the list may have different class types inside of it.

Edit:
Based on everyones responses, this is obviously the wrong way to approach the problem!
I think I will try a cloning method for the objects inside the lit, but I'll also look for a different approach entirely.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why, oh why would you use raw ArrayList in the first place?

Comment: Cast the returned Object to the appropriate type.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (please see link). Can you give some background as to why you even think that you need to do this? I have a strong suspicion that there is a much better approach to solve the overall problem (not the specific code question).

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions. Classes are in `UpperCamelCase`.

Comment: Why do you want to *manually* call an object's constructor? That is severely broken. You already called the objects' constructors implicitly when you created them with *new*.

Comment: Consider changing `ArrayList list` to something more specific such as `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Except for the missing `()` at the end of `new ArrayList`, this code compiles fine, unless you don't have no-arg constructors.

Comment: When you say `new child1()` you _are_ calling the constructor...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Better known as `PascalCase`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: *"The different list items will all have a common parent"* well, what happens if you use the `ArrayList` correctly and declare that it holds that type?

Comment: Im trying to be as generic as possible, so I can't just cast it. in the actual code, its much more separated than the example.

Comment: Again, please explain the overall goal of all of this. Again, this smells of XY problem (see link in my comment above).

Comment: I basically have a class that manipulates ArrayLists and needs to add new instances of the objects already inside, but the list may have different class types inside of it.

Comment: @user3199803: post this as an edit to your question please. It is too important to bury in comments. Can you have your parent type implement Cloneable? or have some type of copy method?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this code that would require you to take a `List` of disparate objects and then create another list, or append to your original list, with new objects of the same classes?

Comment: As Hovercraft says, your problem might be solvable by making the classes implement an interface that will allow you to call some copy method on the objects. Alternatively but similarly you could have a look at creating factories for the objects.

Comment: What you need is a whole new approach.

Comment: Its a genetic algorithm program, so I have a class whose job is to maintain a list of entities, remove the ones that are unfit, and then to repopulate the list back to full capacity. However, i want to keep the class general enough to where I can feed different entity classes into it as long as they extend a 'breedable' class.

Comment: So require all `breedable` to implement a "clone" method which you can later call.

Comment: @jkbot, Yes I might have to try something like that. This method I've used numerous times before when I was only working with 1 class, and could just hard-code in the constructor, it didn't seem like to big of a task to have the class be dynamic.

Comment: @jkbot, cloning should work. I thought this method would be the more clean way, I suppose not!

Comment: Defining an appropriate interface would be a lot cleaner. You would use reflection and instance type checking perhaps in some library that really has to do some real "magic".

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine:

```
public static void arraylist() throws Exception {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    list.add(new X());

    Class clazz = list.get(0).getClass();

    list.add(clazz.getConstructors()[0].newInstance());

}
```

And I'm not saying you should use it..

Comment: Yeah since its hard to find an answer on this, my approach may be wrong. I basically have a class that manipulates ArrayLists and needs add new instances of the objects already inside, but the list may have different class types inside of it.

Comment: It works in that case too (if you do also `list.add(new Y())`, etc.). But you have to take care to call the right constructor with the correct arguments.